# How to properly mock react-native-firebase v6

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, react-native-firebase

I opened an issue on the [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4081) repo, but maybe someone can answer my question here a little faster.

Hey, I'm updating firebase v5 to firebase v6 in our codebase, main integration is done and now I'm trying to get our test suites to pass, I have managed to mock the firebases modules the following way:

```js
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/messaging', () => {
  return () => ({
    hasPermission: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
    subscribeToTopic: jest.fn(),
    unsubscribeFromTopic: jest.fn(),
    requestPermission: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
    getToken: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('myMockToken')),
    onMessage: jest.fn(),
    onNotificationOpenedApp: jest.fn(),
    getInitialNotification: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(false))
  })
})

jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/crashlytics', () => ({}))

jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/app', () => {
  return () => ({
    onNotification: jest.fn(),
    onNotificationDisplayed: jest.fn()
  })
})

jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter')
// jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/RNFBNativeEventEmitter')
```

You can see I have had to mock the RN NativeEventEmitter, which I'm not sure if it's the best choice, in any case, that gets almost all of our test suites to green, however there is one test that fails:

```
$ jest --forceExit src/Sagas/InAppServicesSaga.test.js
 FAIL  src/Sagas/InAppServicesSaga.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

      at _inherits (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/inherits.js:5:11)
      at node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/RNFBNativeEventEmitter.js:29:26
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/RNFBNativeEventEmitter.js:71:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/registry/nativeModule.js:21:1)
```

I have also tried to mock the RNFBNativeEventEmitter object, but that doesn't seem to be working, is there recommended way to mock the package? or anything I might be doing wrong?